# Product price formatter

Tags: commerce

In my shop site, on each of the products listed can we please just list the dollar amount i.e. $80.00(for eg.) - and remove the default currency(eg. AUD) and (GST (exc) )text that follows?
How to formatting the price?

Answer (score 1):

You can use module [Commerce Currency Settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_currency_settings) for formatting of currency.

Comment: Yes it works. but it removing AUD in all pages. I want to show AUD in particular pages like node:product list display page. how to configure using this module. let me know.